# Wireless internet not available unless DNS values are entered on wireless laptop

Tags: dns

Devices: Source computer (Windows XP SP3 & THOMSON ST585 router), Laptop (Windows 7 Home Premium)

I've been using a wireless connection to use the internet on my laptop for a long time. The source is a THOMSON ST585 router. Today, the connection was ok, but it said "No internet access", and no web browsing was possible. After a lot of troubleshooting, where Windows 7 troubleshooting concluded there was a problem in internet access, but not the wireless connection, I changed the DNS setting from "Obtain DNS server automatically" to "Use the following DNS servers" and entered the DNS values that the router uses. Afterwards, internet access became available.

This is confusing me. How has it been working well all that time without the need for entering the DNS numbers and why has this changed now?

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "source" computer?

Comment: So the computer that is wired does not need the DNS settings manually entered, but the wireless computer does? Do you get the same effect from a different computer connected via wireless? You need to narrow it down to the router or the laptop.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like raw IP addresses work OK but you're not getting domain name resolution anymore.  Check the DNS values you entered in the router for correctness.  Or go back the default DHCP settings in both the router and the Win7 computer.

Comment: If you let it automatically obtain on the router level it will get the DNS servers your ISP is setting. I recommend running a benchmark using this tool http://www.grc.com/dns/benchmark.htm and setting your DNS servers on the router level to the fastest one.